# C# label and goto

Tags: c#

This is my full program. Obviously I am a beginner. The problem I face is that if the age is less than zero then it goes back a few lines, but it than asks the user again for the pin also. :( What can I do to fix this ?

```
 using System;

    namespace Examples
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string name;
                string city;
                int age;
                int pin;

                // \n is used for line-break
                Console.Write("Enter your name :  ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("\nEnter Your City :  ");
                city = Console.ReadLine();

                age:
                Console.Write("\nEnter your age :  ");
                age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("\nEnter your pin :  ");
                pin = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (age < 0 || age >= 110)
                {
                    goto age;

                }


                // Printing message to console
                //formatting output
                Console.WriteLine("==============");
                Console.WriteLine("Your Complete Address:");
                Console.WriteLine("============\n");

                Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}", name);
                Console.WriteLine("City = {0}", city);
                Console.WriteLine("Age = {0}", age);
                Console.WriteLine("Pin = {0}", pin);
                Console.WriteLine("===============");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh please don't use the `goto` statement

Comment: Your new, but you'll want to lose your fascination with `goto` ASAP :)

Comment: Gotos are bad and you should feel bad.

Comment: Why are you checking the age after the user entered a pin, rather than after the user entered the age? Maybe you have a good reason for it, but it's causing your problem, so if you don't have a good reason for it, don't do it.

Comment: Move your `if` statement two lines up. Learn to use `while` instead of `goto`. Good luck.

Comment: Is this just for educational purpose? Learn, but don't use `goto` in production.

Comment: I want to check all of them together after the user enters all.

Comment: Also, how can I do this without goto command ? Please tell me with an simple example to do this without goto.

Comment: [Goto statement considered harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) Fix it using the while loop.

Comment: hehe ... dead on the money with my comment about the goto religious war in my answer :)

Comment: GOTO was great when we used to code in Assembly Language. Now things has evolved a bit, please do use conditional structures and loops, it will preserve your haircut.

Comment: Goto is very useful to break out of nested loops in a controlled way. You are abusing it, though, so, indeed get rid of the very habit. I have not used more 1-2 in the last 2-3 years.

Answer (score 3):

So, if I'm understanding this correctly, you want to prompt for the age if it's less than 0 or more than 110?

First of all, don't go with labels, they are ugly and you don't want to use them, instead you could use do while loop, but there are plenty of possibilities:

Also, instead of using the `\n` syntax, you could also use `Console.WriteLine`

```
string name;
string city;
int age;
int pin;

// \n is used for line-break
Console.Write("Enter your name :  ");
name = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("\nEnter Your City :  ");
city = Console.ReadLine();
age = -1;

while (age < 0 || age >= 110)
{
    Console.Write("\nEnter your age :  ");
    age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (age < 0 || age >= 110)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The age must be between 0 and 110.");
    }
}


Console.Write("\nEnter your pin :  ");
pin = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


// Printing message to console
//formatting output
Console.WriteLine("==============");
Console.WriteLine("Your Complete Address:");
Console.WriteLine("============\n");

Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}", name);
Console.WriteLine("City = {0}", city);
Console.WriteLine("Age = {0}", age);
Console.WriteLine("Pin = {0}", pin);
Console.WriteLine("===============");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I want to show an error message to the user too ! that the age should only be between 0 and 110 if he doesnt enter valid age.

Answer (score 1):

u can use functions concept over here, and u should use functions

```
            Console.Write("\nEnter your age :  ");
            age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (age < 0 || age >= 110)
            {
               //show error msg

            }
            Console.Write("\nEnter your pin :  ");
            pin = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

           //if every data is corrent - run function
           showinfo();   
////////////
           showinfo()
           { 
            Console.WriteLine("==============");
            Console.WriteLine("Your Complete Address:");
            Console.WriteLine("============\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}", name);
            Console.WriteLine("City = {0}", city);
            Console.WriteLine("Age = {0}", age);
            Console.WriteLine("Pin = {0}", pin);
            Console.WriteLine("===============");

            Console.ReadLine();}
```

as stated by @noctis ..use of goto should be avoided.. its creates issues ...
also please check for - negetivenumber exception concepts...u can use the exception of ur own too

Answer (score 0):

You could set the pin to -1, and check against it.

also, you might get into a religious war with that GOTO statement ... :) 
usually it's frowned upon, it can surely be avoided here, but some people will say it's ok. up to you really.

I'll put some code together and paste it.

```
void Main()
{
    string name;
    string city;
    int age;
    int pin;

    // \n is used for line-break
    Console.Write("Enter your name :  ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("\nEnter Your City :  ");
    city = Console.ReadLine();

    age = GetAge();

    //... eluded

Console.ReadLine();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
private int GetAge() {
    Console.Write("\nEnter your age :  ");
    int age = -1;
    while (age <0 || age>110) {
        age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    return age;
}
```

using a method would be more appropriate in this case :)

Comment: How can I use it without goto ?

Comment: like the above ... call a method. you might want to check the age for less than 110 i assume as well.

Comment: But I have a 115 year old lady up the street from me!

Comment: @PaulZahra then i seriously hope she's too old to use his program !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Goto Label is a quite old relict from the very beginnings of C, you should avoid it. You may achieve the same by implementing a loop

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your pin :  ");
pin = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
while (age < 0 || age >= 110)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter your age :  ");
   int age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just move your condition before the pin prompt.

```
age:
Console.Write("\nEnter your age :  ");
age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (age < 0 || age >= 110)
{
    goto age;
}

Console.Write("\nEnter your pin :  ");
pin = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```